# Automatically close PuTTY when connection is lost

Tags: linux, bash, putty

I have a script in bash, running multiple PuTTY sessions.
For example, I open the connection to run a couple of commands, when it finishes it saves the values, closes the session, opens a new session and runs a couple more.

This script is supposed to run for 60 hours, more or less, so i need to have everything automated.

My issue is, when the PuTTY session is open, and connected to the device i need, if at some point the device reboots (don't know why it reboots, it just does), a window in putty appears saying the connection was terminated (obviously). The problem is that the window stays open until I press the "ok" button. So my script just stops there until some manual interaction with the PuTTY session.

Is there a way to automatically terminate the PuTTY session if a disconnection happens?

Thank you for your help, if you need some more information just let me know!
regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PuTTY is not intended for automation.

Use [PLink (PuTTY command-line tool)](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter7.html). It's a console application, with the same command line arguments as PuTTY, so the transition should be easy.

---

Though setting ["Close window on exit"](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter4.html#config-closeonexit) to "Always" does work (even if you claim it does not).

Answer (score 1):

See the "Close Window on Exit" option in the Session panel.

[Documentation](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.60/htmldoc/Chapter4.html#config-closeonexit)

Comment: It is set as "Always". I tried changing a lot of parameters in the Session panel but no luck just yet.

Comment: Close window on exit hasn't worked for me either. I'll check out plink.

Comment: Is there also a thing like re-establishing the connection or falling back to the start window?